# drivers for dvd burner

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I just installed an internal DVD burner in my 12.04 Ubuntu box. My first project is burning at .7%, which must be a default driver. On my laptop which is running 14.04, Brasero burns at full speed. Do I need a driver to get the speed in the 12.04 machine?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that when I used K3B, the burner writes at full speed. A fellow Ubuntu user told me that drivers are tricky, and since this is an old IDE computer, brasero may have not recognized the burner because of the ide to SATA adapter. All I know is that everything worked out when I installed K3B.